# Resolve APT package conflicts

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am running a machine with Ubuntu Server 22.04. I have installed CRI-O following the [install section](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/main/install.md#apt-based-operating-systems) on GitHub. It adds a repository for CRI-O with all the required dependencies. With only CRI-O installed everything works fine.

One of the dependencies is the *containers-common* package. Now if I try to install podman from the official repositories I get a package conflict. Podman in the official repositories installs *golang-github-containers-common*, which tries to install the same files as the *containers-common* package from the other repository.

Preferably I want to keep the *container-commmon* package from the CRI-O repository as it is newer. What is the best solution here? Do I have to package podman on my own? Or can I somehow mark *golang-github-containers-common* as a ignored dependency?

At the moment I just removed the broken dependency from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/815371), but this seems like a hacky solution.

**Edit:**
To recreate the issue I removed podman and installed podman again. This is the full output of apt:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  buildah catatonit containernetworking-plugins criu crun fuse-overlayfs golang-github-containernetworking-plugin-dnsname
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libostree-1-1 libyajl2 slirp4netns uidmap
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  golang-github-containers-common golang-github-containers-image
Suggested packages:
  containers-storage docker-compose
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  golang-github-containers-common golang-github-containers-image podman
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 183358 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../golang-github-containers-image_5.16.0-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking golang-github-containers-image (5.16.0-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-github-containers-image_5.16.0-3_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/containers/registries.conf', which is also in package containers-common 100:1-22
Preparing to unpack .../golang-github-containers-common_0.44.4+ds1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking golang-github-containers-common (0.44.4+ds1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-github-containers-common_0.44.4+ds1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/containers/policy.json', which is also in package containers-common 100:1-22
Selecting previously unselected package podman.
Preparing to unpack .../podman_3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking podman (3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-github-containers-image_5.16.0-3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/golang-github-containers-common_0.44.4+ds1-1_all.deb
```

Comment: try doing `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update` and try reinstalling again.

Comment: Please include the output of what APT shows.

Comment: @RishonJR I added the output of apt.

Comment: @RishonJR I also tried to your solution, but it doesn't work. I also don't know why adding the universe repository would solve anything.

Comment: certain dependencies are from the ubuntu repositories like `universe` which is not added by default.